# E-mail alert notification in Grafana

Tags: database, prometheus, alert, grafana, dashboard

Hello friends I have a problem in configuring the email alert notification in Grafana like always getting like

> Failed to send alert notifications

But if I save it's working but while clicking send test that alone does not come properly. Here is my custom.ini config file here below and help me to solve this error friends.

```
[smtp]    
enabled = true
host = smtp.office365.com:587
user = sample12@domain.com
# If the password contains # or ; you have to wrap it with trippel quotes. Ex """#password;"""
password = xxxxxxxxx
;cert_file =
;key_file =
skip_verify = true
from_address = sample12@domain.com
from_name = Grafana
# EHLO identity in SMTP dialog (defaults to instance_name)
;ehlo_identity = dashboard.example.com
```

Comment: Anyone give me suggestions guys?....

Comment: What is the exact error message from the console? What do you mean with "But if I save it's working" ?